# Pebble Heap Corruption With Str(n)cat

Tags: c, heap-memory, heap-corruption, pebble-watch, cloudpebble

When updating my battery display for my Pebble watchface, I get the battery level into int s_battery_level, run it through my toString function (which works 100% of the time, I've tested it), and then append a % and a null terminator, just for good measure. However, for some reason, when that line is run, I get a heap corruption error when the battery drops from 100% to 90% (or 100 to any lower-digit number). I've tried removing/adding in the null terminator, used both strcat() and strncat(), even escaping the %, and nothing has seemed to work. Once I remove the offending line, it works perfectly.

Why is this line corrupting the heap? And optionally, how could I fix/avoid it?

```
static void battery_update_proc(Layer *layer, GContext *ctx) {
  graphics_context_set_text_color(ctx, TxtColor);
  char * lvl = calloc(6,sizeof(char));
  lvl = toString(s_battery_level, lvl);
  //strncat(lvl, "%\0", 2);
  //offending line above ^
  APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "%s", lvl);
  graphics_draw_text(ctx, lvl, s_txt_font, GRect(bound.origin.x + ROUND_OFFSET_BA_X, bound.size.h * .5 + ROUND_OFFSET_BA_Y, bound.size.w, 24), GTextOverflowModeWordWrap, GTextAlignmentCenter, NULL);
}
```

And for good measure, here is the toString function:

```
char * toString(int value, char * result) {
    int digit = digits(value);
    result = calloc(digit + 1, sizeof(char));
    result[digit] = '\0';
    int usedVal = 0;
    for (int i = digit; i > 0; i--)
    {
        int x = (value - usedVal) / pwrOf10(i - 1);
        result[digit - i] = (char) x + '0';
        usedVal = usedVal + (result[digit - i] - '0') * pwrOf10(i - 1);
    }
    return result;
}

int digits(int n) {
    if (n < 0) return digits((n == 0) ? 9999 : -n);
    if (n < 10) return 1;
    return 1 + digits(n / 10);
}

int pwrOf10(int power) {
    int val = 1;
    int i = power;
    while (i > 0)
    {
        val *= 10;
        i--;
    }
return val;
}
```

Comment: `toString()` allocates excactly as many bytes as it uses so there's simply no extra space for anything to append by `strcat()`. You could use `realloc()`  to increase the size of `lvl` and in the end you have to `free()` it to avoid a memory leak

Comment: btw. the second parameter `char *result` of `toString()` makes no sense at all, as you're doing `result = calloc( ... );`.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage The number 6 accounts for 3 digits, the %, the \0, and one for just in case.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Ah, ok. Also, the second parameter does make little sense, but I included because when I tried compiling without the second parameter, it would give an error (or maybe it was a warning) about how it was returning a private variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're allocating memory for `lvl` twice - once in `battery_update_proc` and then again in `toString`. It's the second time that is the issue as it's allocating only enough space for the digits.

And you're then not `free`ing either chunk of memory, so you've got a memory leak too.

As to how to fix it, why not just replace the call to `toString` with `sprintf(lvl,"%d%%",s_battery_level)` and then remember to call `free(lvl)` at the end of the function.

Comment: This would work, but unfortunately sprintf isn't supported by the Pebble SDK for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The eventual answer to the question is that I had to modify toString to add extra space in the calloc() call. Thanks to everyone who reminded me of that technicality!